# getting double value from an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am filling in some objective-c stuff that has been dropped in my lap so sorry if this is simple question. I have the following:

```
[self.distancesArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:.25]];
[self.distancesArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:3.0]]
[self.distancesArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:10.0]];

NSLog(@"here is value: %.2f",[[self.distancesArray objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue]);
```

outputting:

```
2012-05-07 19:15:29.714 AtFoodie[30989:11903] here is value: 0.00
```

How would I get the value of 10?

thx

Comment: how did you initialize your `distancesArray` ?

Comment: Hmm, quite a conundrum. Can you verify that the mutable array is allocated, i.e. distancesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely reason is that your `distancesArray` is actually `nil`—it’s never being initialized. So your `-addObject:` calls are going to `nil` and falling down a hole, and your `-objectAtIndex:` call is doing likewise and returning `nil` (i.e. 0).

Comment: ugh, I'm too tired right now to be coding :-( thx (have to wait to accept answer)